# How to retain a row which is foreign key in another table and remove other duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete, duplicate-data

I have two table:

```
A:
id    code
1      A1
2      A1
3      B1
4      B1
5      C1
6      C1
```

=====================

```
B:
id    Aid
1      1
2      4
```

(`B` doesn't contain the `Aid`  which link to `code C1`)

Let me explain the overall flow: 
I want to make each row in `table A` have different code(by delete duplicate),and I want to retain the `Aid` which I can find in `table B`.If `Aid` which not be saved in `table B`,I retain the id bigger one.

so I can not just do something as below:

```
DELETE FROM A
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id)
                  FROM   A
                  GROUP  BY code,
)
```

I can get each duplicate_code_groups by below sql statement:

```
SELECT code
FROM   A
GROUP  BY code
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Is there some code in sql like

```
for (var ids in duplicate_code_groups){
    for (var id in ids) {
        if (id in B){
            return id
        }
    }

    return max(ids)
}
```

and put the return id into a `idtable`?? I just don't know how to write such code in sql.

then I can do

```
DELETE FROM A
WHERE id NOT IN idtable
```

Comment: Your edit changed the requirement. First you wanted to delete all rows from A with duplicate code (except the row with the highest id), now you also want to delete all rows from A with a code that only occurs once. Are you aware of this changed requirement?

Comment: Also: If your first DELETE statement is the one you want to do (but exclude the rows where the foreign key constraint prohibits deleting), then the rest of your question is just obfuscating (because it conflicts with the first DELETE statement).

Comment: @Werner Henze Let me explain the overall flow: I want to make each row in `table A` have different `code`,and I want to retain the `Aid` which I can find in `table B`.If `Aid` which not be saved in `table B`,I retain the id bigger one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) inside CTE (or sub-query) you can assign numbers for each `Code` based on your ordering and then just join the result-set with your table `A` to make a delete.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Code ORDER BY COALESCE(B.ID,0) DESC, A.ID desc) RN
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.Aid
)
DELETE A FROM A 
INNER JOIN CTE C ON A.ID = C.ID
WHERE RN > 1;

SELECT * FROM A;
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/591a8/1)**

Answer (score 1):

The first select gives you all A.id that are in B - you don't want to delete them. The second select takes A, selects all codes without an id that appears in B, and from this subset takes the maximum id. These two sets of ids are the ones you want to keep, so the delete deletes the ones not in the sets.

```
DELETE from A where A.id not in
(
    select aid from B
    union
    select MAX(A.id) from A left outer join B on B.Aid=A.id group by code having COUNT(B.id)=0
)
```

Actual Execution Plan on MS SQL Server 2008 R2 reveals that this solution performs quite well, it's 5-6 times faster than Nenad's solution :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution

```
 DELETE FROM A
    WHERE NOT id IN
    (
    SELECT MAX(B.AId) 
    FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.aId
    )
```

Comment: this statement will delete the `Aid` which not be saved in `table:B`